# Previous page screenshot preview

Tags: asp.net-4.0, webpage-screenshot

I have a web application in asp.net and C#.

I have three step registration process in which in the end I have to show the preview of all three different pages.

Is it possible to capture previous pages and show them like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the workaround -
Click [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1244725/2286975.aspx)

Comment: I am not getting the defination of this function  Scale( thumbImage, width, height );